# Xcode Unit Test Navigation

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing a test where the I need to test that when the user clicks on register button he/she is taken to the login page after successful registration.

```
 func test_should_navigate_to_login_screen_for_successful_registration() {

        let usernameTextField = self.app.textFields["usernameTextField"]
        usernameTextField.tap()
        usernameTextField.typeText("johndoe")

        let passwordTextField = self.app.textFields["passwordTextField"]
        passwordTextField.tap()
        passwordTextField.typeText("password123")

        // register button will navigate to login view when successfull 
        self.app.buttons["registerButton"].tap()

        print(self.app.navigationBars.element.identifier)

        // If I pause the test and then check the result of self.app.navigationBars.element.identifier
        // then it contains the correct value but if I don't then it contains "Create an Account" which is the text of the back button
        XCTAssertEqual(self.app.navigationBars.element.identifier, "BankAccount.LoginView")
    }
```

the problem is the last assert which checks for self.app.navigationBars.element.identifier value. The value is not available immediately and that is why the test fails. I debugged it and confirmed that eventually the correct value is available.

What is the correct way to test the navigation in Xcode?

SOLUTION (Using Matt's advice in the comment):

This works. Make sure to give accessibilityIdentifier to your view.

func test_should_navigate_to_login_screen_for_successful_registration() {

```
let usernameTextField = self.app.textFields["usernameTextField"]
usernameTextField.tap()
usernameTextField.typeText("johndoe")

let passwordTextField = self.app.textFields["passwordTextField"]
passwordTextField.tap()
passwordTextField.typeText("password123")

// register button will navigate to login view when successfull
self.app.buttons["registerButton"].tap()

let loginView = app.otherElements["LoginView"]
let loginViewExists = loginView.waitForExistence(timeout: 1.0)


XCTAssert(loginViewExists)
```

Comment: It is an integration test.

Comment: How can I add a wait. You mean like sleep(100)

Comment: Do you have any code example? I mean how does it fit in my scenario?